# Oracle like ' 124 % string not working

Tags: sql, oracle

how to find the data like my requirement is col1 is `clob` column value in `col` like:-

```
12.5.4 12.4 12.5 12.4.1 12.5 12.6 12.5 12.5 12.4
```

i need to find data where 12.4 in **beginning, middle and end** if I run this query to get 12.4 in middle of the data it's not working

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 LIKE ' %12.4 '
```

my column is `CLOB` column need to find the data in `CLOB` column separated by space

Example

```
12.4 12.5 12.4.1 

12.5 12.4 12.5

12.4.1 12.4.5 

12.5.1 12.4 12.4.1
```

I am having the data in `CLOB` column with separated by space
12.4 may in first value or middle of data or end of data

```
first row  12.4 12.5 12.6.1
second row 13.5 12.4 12.6.2
third row  12.5 14.5.1 12.4
fourth row 12.4.1 12.6 12.7
```

I need first 3 rows not fourth row  because it's having 12.4.1

Comment: Things are not clear.  So, you want to " find data where 12.4 in beginning, middle and end". So does it mean you want to check if there are three  12.4 s one at beginning, middle and end each? . Further, should it be only 12.4 ? others like 12.4.1 should not be matched? Show few more sample rows with all variations along with the expected output.

Comment: only 12,4   Example 12,6.1 12,4.1 12.4 12,4,2  second row 12.4 14.5. 12.4.5  from this data  I should get 2 rows 12,4

Comment: Don't add comments for sample data. Edit your question  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49586988/edit and show us the expected o/p for few rows. Now, why is there a  comma in your example?

Comment: Fix your data structure so you are not storing a bunch of numeric values in a single string!

Answer (score 2):

Use with double `%` instead :

```
SELECT * FROM myTABLE WHERE COL1 LIKE '%12.4%';
```

This time doesn't matter where your literal is.

Moreoever, may be made parametrical for different values, by using a bind variable :

```
SELECT * FROM myTABLE WHERE COL1 LIKE '%'||'&x'||'%' -- x := 12.4 or a value else.
```

Comment: It is difficult to tell if this answer fits the question, because the requirements aren't clear enough.  If the column value contained '112.43', that would match '%12.4%', but we don't know if that possibility needs to be taken into account or what the desired outcome would be.

Comment: @DaveCosta yes, you're right, if OP wants to have exact match we need to leave spaces around the literal which is ` 12.4 `here. That should be clear in the question.

Comment: I need the exact match 12.4 I give ' % 12.4 % i's not working

Answer (score 2):

> i need to find data where 12.4 in beginning, middle and end

It's not clear from your question whether you want to match any item that contains 12.4 (like 12.4.1) or just an item that is exactly 12.4.  I've assumed you want the exact match.

The simplest way to search for a value in the middle only is `LIKE '% 12.4 %'`.  But this will not match if the 12.4 is at the beginning or end of the column value, because there won't be a matching space before/after the value.

A trick to get around this is to concatenate spaces at the beginning and end of the column value:  `WHERE ' ' || COL1 || ' ' LIKE '% 12.4 %'`.

Another approach is to explicitly cover all the possibilities:  `WHERE ( COL1 LIKE '12.4 %' OR COL1 LIKE '% 12.4' OR COL1 LIKE '% 12.4 %')`.

Comment: I need to find exact 12,4  in my clob column      the issue is  space with 12.4 it's not working how to find  space and then 12,4 and then space  i did not need 12.4.1  in my clob values this 12.4 in first or middle like 13.5 12,4 15.6

Comment: `12,4` or `12.4`? Dave's answer looks like it should work. If it doesn't what you need, please explain the issue in detail. [*It's not working*](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) tends to get downvotes.

Comment: @Reena - stop talking and start listening. Did you read what Dave proposed? The standard way to do it is the condition `' ' || col1 || ' ' like '% 12.4 %'`. Don't reply, don't say another word until you try it first. THEN come back if you think it doesn't do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want to match 12.4 only at word boundaries (beginning,middle and end as separate literal) so, use the below `REGEXP` pattern.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 
REGEXP_LIKE(COL1 ,'(^|\s)12.4($|\s)');
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/615f3/1)

Comment: it's not working it's giving the result 12.4.5 also but I need exact 12.4

Comment: @Reena : Check now. I changed non-word  match(\W)  to just match space(\s)

Comment: it's not giving required result

Comment: @Reena : unless you edit your question providing sample data and expected output, we won't be able to help you. Your explanation isn't helping us either. Don't expect us to guess what you want.

Comment: @Reena : I have added the Demo with your sample data. As expected by you it gives me the 3 rows, and I did not change the query.

Answer (score 0):

This is working when i test in sql fiddle.

```
   select *
    from table1
    where instr(replace(col1,' ','|'), '12.4|') > 0
    or    instr(replace(col1,' ','|'),'|12.4|') > 0
    or    instr(replace(col1,' ','|'),'|12.4') > 0;
```

EDIT: previous answer works in sqlfiddle but not to Reena. I added another answer above which is using instr (find this string on this column). Returns the position of the search string in the given column.

```
Replace space with pipe then do a regular like query.
    select *
    from table1
    where replace(col1,' ','|') like '12.4|%'
    or replace(col1,' ','|') like '%|12.4|%'
    or replace(col1,' ','|') like '%|12.4';
```

Comment: I added a new solution, please try it.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanations, requirements and data is still not clear. But maybe this very simple solution will help you, at least as an idea. Look at row 6 in my example. What is your requirement in this case? And the Kaushik Nayak query works.

```
WITH test_data AS
(
SELECT 1 rn, '12.4 12.5 12.6.1' str FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    '13.5 12.4 12.6.2' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,   '12.5 14.5.1 12.4' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,   '12.4.1 12.6 12.7' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,   '12.4.1 12.4.6 12.4.7' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 6,   '12.4 12.4.1 12.4' FROM dual
)
SELECT rn, str FROM test_data
 WHERE str Like '%12.4%'
MINUS
SELECT rn, str FROM test_data
 WHERE str Like '%12.4.%'
ORDER BY 1
/
```

Output:

```
12.4 12.5 12.6.1
13.5 12.4 12.6.2
12.5 14.5.1 12.4
```